# REST API URL pattern design

Tags: java, spring, rest, api

I am currently developing a REST API.

I am developing an API that returns products associated with a user, and an API that returns products associated with a product.

I can not be sure how to configure the URLpattern to be correct.

What I think is ambiguous is that in the case of the URL returning the product list through the product, the products are repeatedly listed.

Please advise me of a good URL pattern.

I am considering the options below.

1.

```
/domain/v1/relatedProducts/users/{userId}

/domain/v1/relatedProducts/products/{productId}
```

2.

```
/domain/v1/user/{userId}/relatedProducts

/domain/v1/products/{productId}/relatedProducts
```

3.
Please advise other URL patterns.

Comment: A user would not want to know the version ( `v1` ) so that could be put out and the first option looks solid and good. It's my preferation because with a evolving API and more and more filters etc it is better to know which rest you called in generall. With a filter like this `?where=A=xxx&B=xxx&C=xxx` the second option would be not readable or at least less readable than the first option.

But generally This is a question that's likely to get closed/flagged for being opinion based and/or too broad.

Comment: though I do not have much expirence in web domain but I have seen variable parts being pushed on rightost part of the url i.e. `com.organization.group.team.ThomasProfile` , in your case as userid will be unique and will be updating in futute so having it after product seams better idea.

Comment: When i developed the API, i followed this. This is one of nice blog that i read related to REST API design https://blog.mwaysolutions.com/2014/06/05/10-best-practices-for-better-restful-api/

Comment: In fact, there is no need for the version to be in the URL at all, unless you plan to deploy multiple versions within the same .war file.  Remember, each .war file is required to have a unique context root;  they cannot have overlapping URLs, ever.

Comment: Keep version, if you, software needs updates and sometimes you can't make the backward compatible, version help you keep old client running while developing for new ones. From my point of view the resource here is the product, which you are filtering by either user or product, so I would make the query param of products resource

Answer (score 8, accepted):

the products are related to a user, so you should select user first, then list all products. so it should be like

```
/domain/v1/users/{userId}/products
```

notice that i used `users` not `user` and `products` not `relatedProducts`

```
/domain/v1/users/{userId}/products/{productId}
```

also note, there is no thing wrong with `v1` you can keep it or remove it, some of major companies use the version part.

you can follow some best Practices to URL pattern

1. Use nouns but no verbs
2. Use plural nouns
3. Use sub-resources for relations

you can find more helpful details at [restapitutorial Resource Naming](http://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)

Comment: So, in the second case, the following pattern is common for an API querying related products as a product?
/domain/v1/products/{product}/products.

I knew about the pattern you said. 
However, I thought that it was difficult to understand the meaning of the above URL.

Comment: @lucaskim, if you want to query just products, you can use  /domain/v1/products/{product} .